# How do I clear spam e-mails to fake addresses on my domain?

Tags: linux, email

I was just looking around cPanel and noticed that the default mail account is taking up over a gigabyte of storage.  I opened it up in webmail and saw there are over 200,000 spam e-mails sent to randomly generated e-mails like name@mydomain.com.  I am unable to delete them because the webmail installed on cPanel can't handle such a large number of e-mails and won't load the inbox.  How do I clear out these e-mails?

If it matters, I am running CentOS 5.5 on a dedicated box, but I'd rather not have to delete from the command line if at all possible.

Comment: Is the mailbox accessible via IMAP or POP3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a backscatter attack.
More about rejecting these emails here:
http://spamlinks.net/prevent-secure-backscatter.htm

Answer (score 1):

Part of the issue here is that you are simply allowing any email to your domain to work vs letting them :fail:

in cPanel NEVER SET A DEFAULT ADDRESS TO FORWARD ALL MAIL - but rather set it as

**`:fail:  no Such User Here Now Go Away and Spam someone else`**

**Why you should use :fail:**

There are sound technical reasons that you should only use :fail: and not :blackhole: on a cPanel server running exim.

In general the two different settings both discard email not destined for a POP3 account, an alias or a catchall alias. However, ever since cPanel included the verify = recipient code in the standard cPanel ACL section for exim, the way email is discarded differs with the two methods quite starkly:

*Using :blackhole:*

> email is accepted and received into
>   the server in its entirety. It is then
>   processed through exim and only on
>   delivery is it written to the null
>   device (/dev/null) and silently
>   ignored. This wastes server bandwidth
>   as the email data, or body, of the
>   email is accepted into the server.
>   This wastes server resources (CPU,
>   memory and disk I/O) as the email is
>   fully processed by exim before being
>   finally written to /dev/null Because
>   the blackholed email is still
>   processed through the whole of exim
>   before it is finally deleted, if any
>   of the usual checks and routing that
>   any email goes through fails, such
>   email can be placed in the exim mail
>   queue for later reprocessing. This can
>   lead to tens of thousands of
>   blackholed emails accumulating in the
>   exim mail queue which in turn can
>   cause a range of serious server
>   performance and resource problems and
>   will affect the normal and timely
>   delivery of email
>
> This actually breaks the SMTP RFC's
>   because you're not notifying the
>   sending SMTP server that the email is
>   undelivered, which is a requirement
>   Causes emails that will never be
>   delivered onto the exim mail queue
>   because checks such as sender
>   verification are still carried out
>   when processing such emails and if
>   they cannot complete they will stay on
>   the exim mail queue and repeatedly
>   reprocess the email until it is
>   finally discarded (usually 4+ days).
>   This can cause very large mail queues
>   full of spam which is repeatedly
>   processed causing severe performance
>   degradation

Using :fail: the email is never accepted into the server. During the initial SMTP negotiation when the senders SMTP server connects to your SMTP server, the sending SMTP server issues a RCPT command notifying your server which email address the email to follow is intended for. Your server then checks whether the recipient email actually exists on your server (a POP3 account, an alias or a catchall alias) and if it does not, it issues an SMTP DENY which terminates the attempt to deliver the email.

- This saves bandwidth as the email
  data is never received into your
  server
- This saves server resources as the
  email never has to be processed
- This complies with the SMTP RFC's
  because the sending SMTP server
  receives the DENY command
- Your server does not send a bounce
  message (just the DENY command)
- Your server does not send anything to
  the sender of the email (i.e. the
  address in the From: line)
- The sending SMTP server is
  responsible for notifying the
  original sender

Here is a simple explanation of what happens during the SMTP conversation

1. Some other SMTP server connects to
   your server on port 25 and initiates
   an SMTP connection (EHLO command)
2. Other server then sends a message
   saying who they're delivering a
   message for (MAIL FROM command)
3. Other server then sends who the
   message is for on your server (RCPT
   command)
4. At this point your server then
   checks whether the email address in
   the RCPT command can actually be
   delivered on your server. If you do
   not have a catchall alias configured
   to point to an email address
   (Default Address) and you have it
   set to :fail: the following happens:
5. Your server sends back along the
   same connection to the sending
   server "Go away, no-one here" (the
   DENY command)
6. The sender server would then
   normally tell their user that the
   attempt to email your server failed.
   Your server does not send a "bounce"
   message.

Using :fail: is wise - because As far as your server is concerned, all that has happened is a little SMTP chatter and no email has been received and no bounce sent

special thanks to Chirpy on the cpanel forums for an excellent write up and his work with configserver to help with this post.

Comment: This long-winded, copy-and-paste doesn't even attempt to answer the question.